# Continuously check if tcp port is in use

Tags: go

I'm running a bash command to start up a server in the background :  "./starServer &" However, my server takes a few seconds to start up. I'm wondering what I can do to continuously check the port that it's running on to ensure it's up before I actually move on and do other things. I couldn't find anything in the golang api that helped with this. Any help is appreciated!

```
c := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", command)
err := c.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
l, err1 := net.Listen("tcp", ":" + port)
```

Comment: Don't background the process in the shell, it's only making it so you can't properly wait on the child process. Either have your server signal once it's bound the port, or you're going to have to retry the connection until it does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could connect to the port using `net.DialTimeout` or `net.Dial`, and if successful, immediately close it. You can do this in a loop until successful.

```
for {
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", net.JoinHostPort("", port), timeout)
    if conn != nil {
        conn.Close()
        break
    }
}
```

A simple tiny library (I wrote) for a similar purpose might also be of interest: [`portping`](https://github.com/janosgyerik/portping/blob/master/portping.go).

Comment: nice library, maybe has passed a lot of time, but if I  ping the server I see that it does not take into account of the port. If there a way to do this?
Thanks